# How to exeHicute angular unit test cases using Nodejs and Karma

Tags: node.js, angularjs, karma-runner

I have created a unit test in angular js,However I have no idea on how to setup node.js and Karma

So I downloaded the node.js from nodejs.org and installed it.
Open the command prompt and installed karma by executing "npm install karma"

It installed karma.But when I execute my angular js unit test case,it reports some errors
angular is undefined.

I followed the instructions as mentioned in this
http://bardevblog.wordpress.com/2013/07/28/setting-up-angularjs-angular-seed-node-js-and-karma/

Is there any where how to setup Karma and node js to execute angular unit test cases.
Please provide me the information

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Yeoman generator for an Angular.js app](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) to generate a new project and see how it is done there. Please follow the steps under "Usage" on the GitHub page to set up the new project. (For all questions `yo` is asking just hit enter.) Finally, type `grunt test:client`. This executes Karma configured with the `karma.conf.js`.

Answer (score 0):

In your karma config file you need to define all the js files that needs to be loaded and the order in which you specify then is important! Example:

```
files : [
    'source/lib/angular/angular.js', // angular first
    'source/lib/angular/*.js', // then any other angular files (angular-mocks.js, angular-resource.js, angular-route.js ...
    'source/lib/x2js/xml2json.min.js', // some libraries I used
    'source/lib/jquery/jquery.js',
    'source/lib/ui-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js',
    'source/js/*.js', // my own js code
    'source/tests/unit/*.js' // unit tests
     ]
```